# Synchronize UIView layout to OpenGL frames

Tags: ios, layout, opengl-es, uiview

We are developing a game that has 2d elements displayed with `UIViews` over an OpenGL ES view (specifically, we're using GLKit's `GLKView`) and are having problems keeping the positions perfectly in sync.

In the parent view's `layoutSubviews`, we're projecting 3d positions in the world onto the screen, and using those as locations for several `UIView` "markers" in the game. The whole game only updates in response to the user moving the camera, and the camera tells the view `setNeedsLayout` each time it moves.

Everthing's working fine, except that the markers seem to be roughly 1 frame out of sync with the 3d rendering. I say roughly because (1) it's an estimate! and (2) I'm wondering whether there's potentially a multithreading issue: doesn't `GLKView` sync to a special screen refresh callback or something?

Is there some way of hooking a view's layoutSubviews so that it sync's to the 3d view update?

**Update**: Weirdly, calling `layoutIfNeeded` immediately after `setNeedsLayout` makes the problem *worse*! Possibly 2 or more frames out. Really don't understand that!

Answer (score 0):

What's triggering your call to LayoutSubviews?

It all depends where in the RunLoop your call is triggered vs. where your GLK update call is triggered.

In general, for what you're doing, I'd aim to do your layout as a side-effect of the GLK update - i.e. don't wait for layoutSubviews to change your position.

(if you're using OpenGL, then the whole "layout" system isn't much use to you: GLK is running in its own little world of variable frame rate, and you want to make that your reference point)

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible to do correctly without drawing the frames of the video using OpenGL (drawing in the same context so that you are always sure that one frame contains the same time of video and animation). Everyting else you do, framerate compensation, lag prediction, only depends on chance, and will always be a little bit unsynchronized.

I'm not familiar with `UIView` but if there is any way to let it play audio and copy the frames to a texture, do that. The lag in the audio is much easier to compensate and much less noticeable by the humans than in the video.